# preg_match() adding nonsense character

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match, pcre

I'm trying to match DMS latitude/longitude. I've run into a bit of a snag, though. I can detect the pattern so far, but the match keeps returning a nonsense character next to a special character. Here is my code:

```
//Begin code
$pattern = '/[0-9]{1,3}[:| |\x{00B0}]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}[\']{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}["]{0,1}[N|S|E|W]/ui';
$value = "12°30'23\"S";
preg_match($pattern,$value,$matches);
print_r($matches);
//End code
```

and here is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => 12Â°30'23"S )
```

As you can see, an undesired Â exists between the 12 and the °.

Please help!

Comment: Have you verified the charset is set to utf-8 or unicode in the http headers?  see this for more info on php and unicode: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-unicode/index.html

Comment: Well, I feel foolish. Thanks Peter

Comment: @PeterSmith, how about posting that as an answer? That would help get the question off the unanswered questions list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified the charset is set to UTF-8 or Unicode in the HTTP headers? See this page for more info on PHP and Unicode: http://ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-unicode/index.html